# xml to C# objects

Tags: c#, xml

How can I Convert this xml Records object into `List<dp_donorsearch>`. My current code is below but I want to find best way to do this..... any idea?

```
<result>
    <record>
        <field name="donor_id" id="donor_id" value="9879" />
        <field name="first_name" id="first_name" value="Trix5647" />
        <field name="last_name" id="last_name" value="Rabbit657" />
        <field name="email" id="email" value="test@asd..com" />
        <field name="business_phone" id="business_phone" value="" />
        <field name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone" value="" />
        <field name="home_phone" id="home_phone" value="" />
        <field name="address" id="address" value="Street S.W. " />
        <field name="address2" id="address2" value="" />
        <field name="city" id="city" value="Quaker" />
        <field name="state" id="state" value="PA" />
        <field name="zip" id="zip" value="1234" />
        <field name="country" id="country" value="USA" />
    </record>
</result>
```

**C# Code**

```
 public class dp_donorsearch
    {
        public string donor_id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string business_phone { get; set; }
        public string mobile_phone { get; set; }
        public string home_phone { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string address2 { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; } 

        public static List<dp_donorsearch> Load(string url)
        {
            var list = new List<dp_donorsearch>();
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(url);

            list.AddRange(from XmlNode record in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("result/record")
                          select new dp_donorsearch
                          {
                              donor_id = ReadField(record, "donor_id"),
                              first_name = ReadField(record, "first_name"),
                              last_name = ReadField(record, "last_name"),
                              email = ReadField(record, "email"),
                              business_phone = ReadField(record, "business_phone"),
                              mobile_phone = ReadField(record, "mobile_phone"),
                              home_phone = ReadField(record, "home_phone"),
                              address = ReadField(record, "address"),
                              address2 = ReadField(record, "address2"),
                              city = ReadField(record, "city"),
                              state = ReadField(record, "state"),
                              zip = ReadField(record, "zip"),
                              country = ReadField(record, "country")
                          });

            return list;
        }


        private static string ReadField(XmlNode node, string nodeName)
        {
            var selectSingleNode = node.SelectSingleNode("field[@name = '" + nodeName + "']");
            if (selectSingleNode != null && selectSingleNode.Attributes != null)
                return selectSingleNode.Attributes["value"].Value;

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you try using Deserialize method of XmlSerializer class. You only need one line (apart from your class definition) to deserialize the xml into you data structure.

Comment: I like your idea but can you suggest me how it fit in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you deserialize it into your class structure

Reference xml namespace

```
 using System.Xml;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

deserialize

```
        string input =
            "<result>\n" +
               "<record>" +
                   "<field name=\"donor_id\" id=\"donor_id\" value=\"9879\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" value=\"Trix5647\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" value=\"Rabbit657\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value=\"test@asd..com\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"business_phone\" id=\"business_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"mobile_phone\" id=\"mobile_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"home_phone\" id=\"home_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"address\" id=\"address\" value=\"Street S.W. \" />" +
                   "<field name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" value=\"\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"city\" id=\"city\" value=\"Quaker\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"state\" id=\"state\" value=\"PA\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"zip\" id=\"zip\" value=\"1234\" />" +
                   "<field name=\"country\" id=\"country\" value=\"USA\" />" +
               "</record>" +
           "</result>";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
        Result result = serializer.Deserialize(new System.IO.StringReader(input)) as Result;
```

Class definition

```
[XmlRoot("result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement("record")]
    public Record[] Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<result>" +
                   "<record>" +
                       "<field name=\"donor_id\" id=\"donor_id\" value=\"9879\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" value=\"Trix5647\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" value=\"Rabbit657\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value=\"test@asd..com\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"business_phone\" id=\"business_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"mobile_phone\" id=\"mobile_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"home_phone\" id=\"home_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address\" id=\"address\" value=\"Street S.W. \" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"city\" id=\"city\" value=\"Quaker\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"state\" id=\"state\" value=\"PA\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"zip\" id=\"zip\" value=\"1234\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"country\" id=\"country\" value=\"USA\" />" +
                   "</record>" +
                  "<record>" +
                       "<field name=\"donor_id\" id=\"donor_id\" value=\"9879\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" value=\"Trix5647\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" value=\"Rabbit657\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value=\"test@asd..com\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"business_phone\" id=\"business_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"mobile_phone\" id=\"mobile_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"home_phone\" id=\"home_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address\" id=\"address\" value=\"Street S.W. \" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"city\" id=\"city\" value=\"Quaker\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"state\" id=\"state\" value=\"PA\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"zip\" id=\"zip\" value=\"1234\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"country\" id=\"country\" value=\"USA\" />" +
                   "</record>" +
               "</result>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);


            var listDict = doc.Descendants("record").AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => x.Descendants("field")
                .GroupBy(y => y.Attribute("name").Value, z => z.Attribute("value").Value)
                .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
                .ToList());



        }
    }
}

​
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution more like your original

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input =
                "<result>" +
                   "<record>" +
                       "<field name=\"donor_id\" id=\"donor_id\" value=\"9879\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" value=\"Trix5647\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" value=\"Rabbit657\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value=\"test@asd..com\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"business_phone\" id=\"business_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"mobile_phone\" id=\"mobile_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"home_phone\" id=\"home_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address\" id=\"address\" value=\"Street S.W. \" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"city\" id=\"city\" value=\"Quaker\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"state\" id=\"state\" value=\"PA\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"zip\" id=\"zip\" value=\"1234\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"country\" id=\"country\" value=\"USA\" />" +
                   "</record>" +
                  "<record>" +
                       "<field name=\"donor_id\" id=\"donor_id\" value=\"9879\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"first_name\" id=\"first_name\" value=\"Trix5647\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"last_name\" id=\"last_name\" value=\"Rabbit657\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value=\"test@asd..com\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"business_phone\" id=\"business_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"mobile_phone\" id=\"mobile_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"home_phone\" id=\"home_phone\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address\" id=\"address\" value=\"Street S.W. \" />" +
                       "<field name=\"address2\" id=\"address2\" value=\"\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"city\" id=\"city\" value=\"Quaker\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"state\" id=\"state\" value=\"PA\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"zip\" id=\"zip\" value=\"1234\" />" +
                       "<field name=\"country\" id=\"country\" value=\"USA\" />" +
                   "</record>" +
               "</result>";

            List<dp_donorsearch> list = dp_donorsearch.Load(input);


        }
        public class dp_donorsearch
        {
            public string donor_id { get; set; }
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string business_phone { get; set; }
            public string mobile_phone { get; set; }
            public string home_phone { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string address2 { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
            public string zip { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }

            public static List<dp_donorsearch> Load(string input)
            {
                List<dp_donorsearch> list = new List<dp_donorsearch>();
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

                var listDict = doc.Descendants("record").AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        dict = x.Descendants("field")
                            .GroupBy(y => y.Attribute("name").Value, z => z.Attribute("value").Value)
                            .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())
                    });

                foreach(var dict in listDict)
                {
                    dp_donorsearch newDp = new dp_donorsearch();
                    list.Add(newDp);

                    newDp.donor_id = dict.dict["donor_id"];
                    newDp.first_name = dict.dict["first_name"];
                    newDp.last_name = dict.dict["last_name"];
                    newDp.email = dict.dict["email"];
                    newDp.business_phone = dict.dict["business_phone"];
                    newDp.mobile_phone = dict.dict["mobile_phone"];
                    newDp.home_phone = dict.dict["home_phone"];
                    newDp.address = dict.dict["address"];
                    newDp.address2 = dict.dict["address2"];
                    newDp.city = dict.dict["city"];
                    newDp.state = dict.dict["state"];
                    newDp.zip = dict.dict["zip"];
                    newDp.country = dict.dict["country"];
                }

                return list;
            }



        }
    }
}
​
```